# Python - <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000002B70E10>

Tags: python, python-3.x

**CODE**

```
class MyClass(object):
    def MyMethod(self):
        print(self)           

MyObject = MyClass()
print(MyObject.MyMethod())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000002B70E10 >
```

What does this `__main__` mean? And what is being passed in the `self` parameter?

Comment: You're also calling print with the results of a method that does not return anything.  So it'll just print "None".

Answer (score 5):

> What does this `__main__` mean?

The script invoked directly is considered the `__main__` module. It can be imported and accessed the same way as any other module.

> And what is being passed in the self parameter?

The reference contained in `MyObject`.

Answer (score 2):

`__main__` is the name of the current module if you run directly from the commandline. If you would import the module from another module `import my_module`, it will known by this name. Accordingly, the print would say:

```
< my_module.MyClass object at 0x0000000002B70E10 >
```

Comment: Except without the double underscores.

Comment: Partial-copy-paste-problem.

Answer (score 0):

`__main__` is the name of the module that your script is running in.  You didn't define a library, so it's not a module with a name.

As for `self`, it's the equivalent of `this` in C++ or Java, but Python requires you to name it explicitly.  See [a tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

First:

`__main__` indicates that the class running the method is the primary file being run - the file that you clicked on or that you typed into terminal is the one where the class presides. That's why it's good practice to write

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #do stuff
```

on your test code - this guarantees that your test code will only run if the code is being run from the originally called file. It's also why you should never write top level code, especially if you want to multi-thread later on!

Self is a key word that identifies the class. Every method needs to have the first parameter"self" - watch out, if you don't, an error will NOT be thrown, your code will just fail. Calling self.variable indicates a look-up to a class variable as opposed to a local variable (just within that method) or a global variable (avaliable to everyone). Similarly, calling self.methodName() calls a method belonging to that class.

So:

```
class Foo: #a new class, foo
    def __init__( self ):
        #set an object variable to be accessed anywhere in this object
        self.myVariable = 'happy' 
        #this one's a local variable, it will dissapear at the end of the method's execution
        myVaraible = sad 
        #this calls the newMethod method of the class, defined below. Note that we do NOT write self when calling.
        self.newMethod( "this is my variable!" )

    def newMethod (self, myVariable):
        #prints the variable you passed in as a parameter
        print myVariable 
        #prints 'happy', because that's what the object variable is, as defined above
        print self.myVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.You can use list.
For example →

```
print(list(your object))
```

Comment: Resolved what? I can't see how this answer addresses OP's question.

Comment: Why do you think that? I just want to help you. I don't think much of anything else.
You can also see my Chinese article. I did solve my problem.
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41185868/article/details/81026860

Comment: I feel very sad. I shouldn't have helped you